What is the default username & password for Oracle sql in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS?
I have installed oracle sql on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS by watching a youtube video. i am stuck connecting to the database. i don't know what is my username and password for connecting to oracle database.
When i tried user: scott and Pass: tiger then it showing i have problem with the network adapter.

I tried to search on youtube for solution but that only shows solves on windows using sqlplus but i didn't found anything using Ubuntu platform.

Oracle database is not supported on Ubuntu. Install a supported operating system such as Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux or SUSE Enterprise Linux (all other linux OS are unsupported). If you are not using one of those then create a virtual machine running one of those OS and install the database in the VM. However, you do not appear to have installed an Oracle database and have only installed SQL Developer (which is a client application used to talk to databases and is not a database).

If something like this is what you watched, then it means that you installed SQL Developer, a GUI tool which is used to connect to Oracle database. It means that you have to install a database itself as well (or have it accessible over the network).
Ubuntu probably isn't the best choice; perhaps you'd rather install VirtualBox and use one of pre-configured Oracle virtual machines.
I presume that Database App Development VM might be the right choice for you as it contains (among other things) both Oracle database and Oracle SQL Developer, which should get you started.

The link you mentioned i have watched that video to install Oracle DB. Now i can't go back to windows. but have to work with oracle database and i am new to oracle database. so, if there is any video please suggest me or share the full process to make the connection of oracle DB. If the connection is possible using vscode that's also fine just need the connection.

No, you did not install Oracle database. You installed only SQL Developer. Re-read what I already wrote; there's nothing I'd like to add to it (apart from the fact that I prefer reading documentation and following Installation Guide, instead of watching YouTube videos).
